# The graph of a continuous map is a topological manifold

Tags: general-topology, continuity, manifolds

To show that the graph of a continuous map is a topological manifold, I need (among other things) to proof the following:

> Let $U$ be an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, and $f: U \to \mathbb{R}^k$ a continuous map. Then the map $\phi_f: U \to \mathbb{R}^{n+k}$ that associates $x \in U$ to $(x,f(x))$ is continuous.

I do not know how to prove it. I tried to show that the pre-image of every open subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n+k}$ is open in $U$ but I did not succeed. Also, I should not use the topological notion of product space since showing that the graph of a continuous map is a manifold appears before product spaces in the book I am reading.

Comment: The $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ argument to show continuity at each $x \in U$ is a bit tedious but not very hard. By composing with translations, you can assume $x = 0$ and $f(x) = 0$, which simplifies the algebra.

Answer (score 3):

Whenever $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ are three topological spaces and we equip $Y\times Z$ with the product topology, a function $\phi\colon X\to Y\times Z$ is continuous if and only if ${\rm pr}_Y\circ \phi\colon X\to Y$ and ${\rm pr}_Z\circ \phi\colon X\to Z$ are continuous. This is a trivial consequence of the definition of product topology. In other terms, if $\phi(x) = (\phi_1(x),\phi_2(x))$, then $\phi$ is continuous if and only if both $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$ are continuous.

In your case, $X = U$, $Y = \Bbb R^n$, $Z = \Bbb R^k$, $\phi(x) = (x,f(x))$, $\phi_1$ is the inclusion $U\hookrightarrow \Bbb R^n$ and $\phi_2=f$.

Don't let $\Bbb R^n$ distract you.

Comment: Good to know that it is a more general result. Do you know if it is possible to prove it without the notion of product topology? Since in the book I am reading the part on product spaces comes after so I do not think we are supposed to use this notion (that is unknown to me for now) but every idea I tried required somehow a notion of product space…

Comment: Then do an $\epsilon$-$\delta$ proof, using the norm $\|(x,y)\| = \|x\|+\|y\|$ in $\Bbb R^{n+k} = \Bbb R^n\times \Bbb R^k$. But it is very strange to be talking about topological manifolds without having covered basic topology first. I wonder what is your instructor thinking by assigning this.

Comment: It’s in the book “Introduction to topological manifolds” by John M. LEE